# How can I duplicate values in pd.Dataframe for new value in column

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have dataframe

```
   A B C id
0  1 2 3 1
1  2 3 4 1
```

given list of values for `id`, for example `[1,2,3]` how can I obtain

```
   A B C id
0  1 2 3 1
1  2 3 4 1
2  1 2 3 2
3  2 3 4 2
4  1 2 3 3
5  2 3 4 3
```

in a most convenient and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Try repeat the index, then repeat the id list:

```
id_list = [1,2,3]

(df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(id_list))]
   .assign(id=np.repeat(id_list, len(df)))
)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  id
0  1  2  3   1
0  1  2  3   1
0  1  2  3   2
1  2  3  4   2
1  2  3  4   3
1  2  3  4   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another technique (just for learning purpose, not efficient):

concat and then multiple the `id` with list element after grouping them together.

```
idx = [1,2,3]
y = pd.concat([df]*len(idx))
y.assign(id=y.groupby(y.index)['id'].transform(lambda x:x.mul(idx))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

|  | A | B | C | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |